# Why did the YouTube thumbnail API fall off?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube

There are Google spreadsheets that help you create YouTube playlists by inserting links: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGinL-nMddefODzZnoXcv2UPxrFDFFGFNDX44dBkOpk/edit?usp=sharing

Previously, video previews were loaded in column "C". The last couple of days it stopped working.
Maybe something has changed in the YouTube API?

[image]

Here is a different template, but I think the principle is the same: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15PggAMR283kVQZtfKNnhWP-7YcZWi6X3Opgn_nYYZzI/edit#gid=167172621

Moreover, the first time you open the spreadsheets, there are previews. Then they disappear.

I tried different templates and browsers

Comment: As far as I understand you don't provide (even through the sheets you shared) how the thumbnails are loaded.

Comment: When I saw your Spreadsheet, it seems that you use `=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B = "", "", IMAGE(REPLACE("https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/IMG/hqdefault.jpg",25,3,B2:B), 4, 80, 120)))`. "B2:B" is the video ID. In this case, for example, as a workaround, how about modifying your formula without using `ArrayFormula` as follows? `=BYROW(B2:B,LAMBDA(x,IMAGE(REPLACE("https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/IMG/hqdefault.jpg",25,3,x),4,80,120)))` But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.